# Why can't Visual Basic convert my datatable into an excel datatable?

Tags: vb.net, excel, datatable, interop, export

I'm trying to make a program with a local database where I can have an overview for our company savings. Nothing really special. Anyway, I want to export the dataset to an excel file when I click on the export button. This is my code

```
Dim dt As DataTable

    Dim xl As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    ds = GeldopslagDataSet
    xl.UserControl = True
    Dim oldCI As System.Globalization.CultureInfo = _
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = _
        New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")
    xl.Workbooks.Add()
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = oldCI
    xl.ActiveSheet.Name = "Spaardoel"
    xl.Visible = True
    xl.Range("A1").Value = "Loading the DataSet...."

    Try
        xl.ScreenUpdating = False

        dt = ds.Tables("Geldopslag")

        'Add the column headings for Geldopslag
        Dim dc As DataColumn
        Dim iCols As Int32 = 0
        For Each dc In dt.Columns
            xl.Range("A1").Offset(0, iCols).Value = dc.ColumnName
            iCols += 1
        Next
        'Add the data
        Dim iRows As Int32
        For iRows = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            xl.Range("A2").Offset(iRows).Resize(1, iCols).Value = _
              dt.Rows(iRows).ItemArray()
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
    Finally
        xl.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Try

    'Make the sheet pretty
    With xl.ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
        .AutoFilter()
        .AutoFormat(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlRangeAutoFormat.xlRangeAutoFormatSimple)
    End With

    xl = Nothing
```

Whem I start DeBugging I catch the following error:

COMException was unhandled
Old format or invalid type library. (Exception of HRESULT: 0x80028018 (TYPE_E_INVDATAREAD))

Furthermore, as you can see, i set xl as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application instead of using Imports Microsoft.interop.excel on top. When I do this I get the error that my datatable couldn't be converted into an excel datatable.

Comment: Did the snippet solve your problem? If so mark it as solves otherwise comment what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I use this function and it works perfect:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Public Class ExcelTools

' Export a DataTable into an Excel Datasheet
Public Shared Function DatatableToExcel(ByVal aDataTable As DataTable) As Boolean
    Dim myExcel As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Try
        ' Excel.Application
        myExcel.Application.Workbooks.Add()
        myExcel.Visible = True
        Dim myColumn As DataColumn
        Dim colIndex As Integer
        Dim rowIndex As Integer
        For Each myColumn In aDataTable.Columns
            colIndex += 1
            myExcel.Cells(1, colIndex) = myColumn.ColumnName
        Next

        Dim myRow As DataRow
        rowIndex = 1
        For Each myRow In aDataTable.Rows
            rowIndex += 1
            colIndex = 0
            Dim myColumn2 As DataColumn
            For Each myColumn2 In aDataTable.Columns
                colIndex += 1
                myExcel.Cells(rowIndex, colIndex) = myRow( _
                  myColumn2.ColumnName)
            Next myColumn2
        Next myRow
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

    myExcel.Quit()

End Function
end class
```

Comment: Thanks ruedi! But my problem is still the same. I appearantly miss a library file for the excel application. It can't add a new workbook. I have no clue what dll file I need to enable a application driven order to add a new workbook in Excel

Comment: Did xou set the reference to microsoft excel 14.0 under add reference for your project?